# facebook signed request sent without signature

Tags: facebook

I have a facebook app and in my page tab I'm trying to display a interactive web page. When first visiting the page tab, a regular signed request with a signature is sent, but every further request only has a signed_request with the data and no signature attached.

I could not find anything in the documentation about requests without a signature. So did facebook change something in that regard? Do I need to sent a different request to get a signature?

Comment: The `signed_request` is only POSTed to your app on initial load into the iframe – once you start navigating inside your app, you will not get that parameter any more (unless you are reloading the whole Facebook page around it too). So where does your signed_request on the following requests even come from?

Comment: It is appended to the GET request as a query string parameter, but without a signature...

Comment: Well then somebody must have appended this GET parameter …

Comment: That makes a lot of sense and solves my problem. Thank you very much